# Is there any way to access a realm instance (created by a javascript code) by a java native module (react native bridge)?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, realm

I've been using realm in my react-native app through javascript API to persist some user data. Now I need to access this realm instance from a native module (react-native bridge in Android) to retrieve this persisted data. Could you tell me how can I do it? I've already installed Realm in my gradle settings, and initiated a default config in MainApplication.java. But I'm getting this error:

**io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Directory at path 'data/data/com.moodar/file/default.realm' does not exist**

In javascript environment I created a default instance, so I thought I could access this default instance through java interface too.

Here is my overridden onCreate method on MainApplication.java:

```
super.onCreate();

final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 14;

Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
        .Builder()
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
        .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading official documentation I found a solution: Dynamic Realms.
There's no need to create java schemas, you can query objects using Strings.